# What correlation test can I use for non-normal and binary data?

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to assess correlation between a few different variables - some are numeric, some are presence/absence (labelled 1,0). I've done some googling but can't seem to figure it out being a stats novice - are there any tests I can use to check correlations between non-normal and binary data? Really appreciate any help

Comment: Are you after linear correlations? Or monotonic correlations? Or some more general association?

Answer (score 1):

If by correlation you mean a measure of goodness-of-fit of a specific class of curves (like Pearson correlation for linearly related variables), you can use Pearson correlation for non-normal data. As you can read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105469/263742), the normality assumption for Pearson correlation is important for the calculation of p-value and confidence intervals. For the $r$ value specifically, normality is not required. However, you can use Spearman and Kendall correlation, which the normality assumption is not required for the calculation of p-value and confidence intervals, and also extend the class of functions to fit your data, that is, monotonic functions (which includes linear). It's important to say that [Spearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) and [Kendall correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) work on continuous, discrete, and ordinal data, which means that your "Yes/No" or "Presence/Absence" must have an ordering. From Presence to Absence, for example.

Binary data with these rank-based correlations (Spearman and Kendall) can be tricky due to ties, but in some implementations such as in the $R$ language and its common packages, this is taken into consideration.

However, if you mean correlation in the general sense, a statistical dependence measure, how related are a set of variables, then you can use [Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). MI will provide you a degree of relationship (statistical dependence) between two variables regardless of the form in which such relationship occurs. There are many $R$ packages and other software that can calculate it for you, which is pretty straightforward for discrete variables and a bit trickier for continuous ones.

Comment: What is linearly related variable?

Comment: If you meant linearly related variable*s*, two variables are linearly related if their statistical relationship can be well represented through a linear function.

Comment: I did upvote your answer using my hindsight. But, could you please help me understand difference between a measure of goodness of fit and r value? Does r value here,reflect Pearson coefficient or sample correlation ?

Comment: Thanks. In my answer, when I said $r$ I meant the Pearson correlation coefficient. For goodness-of-fit, R-squared would be more appropriate if you believe a line is an adequate fit for the relationship between your $X$ and $Y$ variables.